# Memory Leak/Issues with Valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind

Here's my code, followed by the error message, could someone please show me what is wrong?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// wscramble.cpp
// Word Scramble guessing game
// Illustrates string library functions, character arrays,
// arrays of pointers, etc.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

// Scramble the letters of this string randomly
void permute(char items[], int len);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
// check if user has entered enough number of arguments
if (argc < 2) {
   cout << "Error: Not enough number of argument entered!" << endl;
   return 0;
}

// create a stream to read file
ifstream fp(argv[1]);

// check if file is opened
if (!fp.is_open()) {
   cout << "Failed to open file!" << endl;
   return 0;
}

// read number of words to read
int numWords;
if (!(fp >> numWords)) {
   cout << "Error: Failed to read subsequent number of words!" << endl;
   return 0;
}

// allocate memory to array
char **wordBank;
wordBank = new char*[numWords];

// hold string to read in from file
char buffer[41];

for (int i = 0; i < numWords; ++i) {
   // read word from the file
   fp >> buffer;

   // create new array to hold this
   char *newWord = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];

   // copy content from buffer to new memory location
   strcpy(newWord, buffer);

   // set pointer in wordBank
   wordBank[i] = newWord;
}

// close the file
fp.close();

srand(time(0));
char guess[80];
bool wordGuessed = false;
int numTurns = 10;

// Pick a random word from the wordBank
int target = rand() % numWords;
int targetLen = strlen(wordBank[target]);

// Make a dynamically-allocated copy of the word and scramble it
char* word = new char[targetLen+1];
strcpy(word, wordBank[target]);
permute(word, targetLen);

// An individual game continues until a word
// is guessed correctly or 10 turns have elapsed
while (!wordGuessed && numTurns > 0) {
cout << "Scrambled word: " << word << endl;
cout << "What do you guess the original word is? ";
cin >> guess;
wordGuessed = (strcmp(guess, wordBank[target]) == 0);
numTurns--;
}
if (wordGuessed) {
cout << "You win!" << endl;
}
else {
cout << "Too many turns...You lose!" << endl;
}
delete [] word;
return 0;
}
// Scramble the letters. See "Knuth shuffle" on Wikipedia.
void permute(char items[], int len) {
for (int i = len-1; i > 0; --i) {
int r = rand() % i;
char temp = items[i];
items[i] = items[r];
items[r] = temp;
}
}
```

The following is the error summary I have recieved:

```
==3222== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3222==     in use at exit: 88 bytes in 7 blocks
==3222==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 3 frees, 8,854 bytes allocated
==3222== 
==3222== 88 (48 direct, 40 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2 
==3222==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3222==    by 0x401088: main (in /home/student/cs103/lab-valgrind/scramble)
==3222== 
==3222== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3222==    definitely lost: 48 bytes in 1 blocks
==3222==    indirectly lost: 40 bytes in 6 blocks
==3222==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3222==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3222==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3222== 
==3222== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3222== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The command I used was: $ valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./scramble wordbank.txt

Comment: Please post the error message in textual form, not as an image.

Comment: The only resources you are allocating that I spotted in a cursory reading are a file pointer and the abomination that is wordBank (which is one resource you are failing to free). You should rewrite it using `std::vector<std::string> wordBank`, removing the need for any kind of manual resource management. Odds are the problem will just disappear.

Comment: ^How would I do that?

Comment: Where would I do that, to be more specific

Comment: Are you using manual resource allocation for academic purposes? If you're not, then use std::string and std::vector, they take care of dynamic allocation for you.

Comment: char **wordBank;  could be replaced by std::vector< std::string > wordBank; and any of the following two can be replaced by a std::string.   char buffer[41]; char *newWord = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];

Comment: I do need to use manual resource allocation, do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: It looks like you're just forgetting to `delete[] wordBank` at the end.  You're deleting the words within it, but not the containing array that you initially allocated.

Comment: Upon re-read, it looks like you're also not calling `delete[]` on each of the words that you allocated within your `wordBank`.  As others noted, it'd be better to use containers from `std::` to take care of this for you, but if you must manage memory yourself, there should always be a one-to-one relationship between calling `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question exactly as asked:

When managing memory allocation manually, as you are, you need have a `delete[]` for every `new[]` (likewise `delete` and `new`).  The only memory that you've allocated and also remembered to delete is the scrambled word.  Valgrind is complaining because you need to delete:

- All the words in `wordBank`
- `wordBank` itself

Unless I missed something in your code, something like this at the end of the program should suffice:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numWords; ++i)
{
    delete[] wordBank[i];
}
delete[] wordBank;
```

P.S. -- it may be worth exploring various compilation options and Valgrind options that could help pinpoint the source of your problems more exactly.  If you get things configured right, it's often possible to see the exact line number where the leaked resource was allocated.